# How to develop a dual list box for MVC4 - where items can be selected from left area and selected items seen in right area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

I am looking for a solution to develop a dual list for MVC 3 project in asp.net.

What I try to build is:

```
TEXTAREA1  LeftArrowButton    TEXTAREA2
           RightArrowButton
```

, where `TEXTAREA1` includes the items that the end user might select via `RightArrowButton`, `TEXTAREA2` includes the selected items by end user and the end user can use `LeftArrowButton` to remove a selected item.

What I am currently using is a listbox like below:

```
<div class="ColumnTwo"><%= Html.ListBox("userInput.GroupOrder", groupOrderParameter.DropDownValues, new { size = "5", Multiple = "multiple" })%></div>
```

However, even though it is working, it is not working as supposed since:

1. The end user needs to press CTRL or SHIFT keys while selecting
   multiple items.
2. The order that the enduser will select the items matters

Therefore, I will need a structure I told above, where the user will not need to press and hold any key on the keyboard (will use the arrow buttons) and I also can see in which order the user selected the items.

My problem is, I could not manage to develop such a structure. Is there a Html.SOMETHING that I can use for that purpose, or I need to build it in another way (how?)? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I found an example on: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows/desktop/uxguide/ctrl-list-boxes#usage

[image]

So seems like a "listbuilder" is what I am looking for, but I don't see Html.ListBuilder or any similar option provided. Anyone experienced how to develop this one?

Comment: You should multiple select list . Third party jqury library

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Two-side-Multi-Select-Plugin-with-jQuery-multiselect-js.html

Comment: @AsifRaza This plugin is good, but I couldn't find a way to disable its auto sorting specialty. Any idea how I can keep the order with this??

Comment: Please explore official site, hope there will be order function. Before to asign list to order first.